# C# WPF размытость на контролах при загрузке приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Иногда при загрузке приложения если нажать на combo box или header столбца DataGridView он розмывается на долю секунды. Как я понимаю ето особенности рендеринга контролов, но все же может кто-небудь встречал подобное? я бы хотел избавиться от этого

Comment: Могу посоветовать архиполезную статью [Откуда «мыло» в WPF и как с ним бороться](https://habr.com/post/216833/).